# Is there an analogue for a universal reference?

Tags: rust

How do I specify a "universal reference" analogue in Rust?
Precisely, I would like to write something similar to the following C++:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void func(T&& t) {
  otherfunc(std::forward(t));
}
```

How should I go about it in Rust ?

For instance, I do not want to type two times the same code just to cover two different cases if the value is passed as a reference or as a moved value, i.e. Let's say, I want to write a container and there must be an `add` method.

How should I write it to cover both cases and do not resort to copy-paste for the reference and moved value cases?

Comment: how about generics?

Comment: Rust rules about generics and references are much saner than C++'s and doesn't need anything like forwarding references.

Comment: Can you show what problem (concrete or potential) you are intending to solve this in Rust? As others said, it's probably not necessary due to Rust's different rules (no transparent references, no automatic rvalue<->lvalue conversions), but the only way to be sure is to examine a concrete example.

Comment: @user4815162342

I do not understand that stack of minuses, since the question is actual. For instance, I do not want to type two times the same code just to cover two different cases if the value is passed as a reference or as a value, i.e. Let's say, I want to write a container and there must be an `add` method. How should I write it to cover both cases and do not resort to copy-paste for reference and moved value?

Comment: @Netwave, The question IS about generics, but in all cases considered I have to specify which one I'm expecting to get a ref or a value. And my question is how to write the code in a way that would do not mind either of them.

Comment: @mcarton,

That's all well and good, but I do not ask about sanity, I ask how not to resert to copy-paste and how to stick to the `DRY ` principle, not sacrificing the performance for unnecessary copies.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, so I can't explain the "stack of minuses", but my question remains: could you show Rust code where you want to use this feature and where you currently have repetition? If you're adding to a container, then the container will be generic over `T`, so your add just accepts `T`, and passing `&T` to it will result in a compile-time error. If the caller holds `&T`, they'll call `add(my_ref.clone())`, which roughly corresponds to a copy ctor. And `T` can itself be reference  to another type, no problem there. There is no duplication I'm aware of. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dronte7 Despite my comment, I did not actually downvote this question. I think this is a fair question to ask when you don't know Rust and try to compare it to C++. My comment was just there to mention that Rust doesn't have them because they are not needed.

Comment: C++'s forward references are mostly there to help with the case where a function should transparently accept a `T` or `T&`. This is not a thing in Rust, since you pass references or values explicitly, unlike C++. And for the rare cases where one does want to accept values or references transparently, [`std::borrow::Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) covers this. Unfortunately, when I made my comment, I didn't have much time to develop it further, and I've left C++ behind years ago, and do not feel confident enough to make a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible to write functions that accept both references and owned values. When there's a generic argument `T`, it can be instantiated with reference types such as `&str`.

For example, this works:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

fn add<T: Add>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T::Output {
    lhs + rhs
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(add(5, 37), add(&5, &37));
}
```

That's because both `i32` and `&i32` implement the `Add` trait.

Traits that are quite often used in function arguments are:

- `AsRef<T>`
- `Into<T>`

For example:

```rust
fn foo(arg: impl AsRef<str>) {
    let _: &str = arg.as_ref();
}

fn bar(arg: impl Into<Box<i32>>) {
    let _: Box<i32> = arg.into();
}

fn main() {
    foo("hello");
    foo(String::from("world"));
    foo(&String::from("!"));

    bar(42);
    bar(Box::new(42));
}
```